# How to lock OS with Python? (Linux)

Tags: python, operating-system, locking

I want to write a Python program that locks my ability to interact with OS until I do a specific action. What I mean by that is that I am not allowed to interact with any programs on my pc until I am, lets say done writing x amount of words in Word, or something similar. Is there any guide on how to do that, or some kind of python module that is related to this?

Edit:

I am inspired by a program called Coldturkey's "micromanager"
link: https://getcoldturkey.com/micromanager/
Which blocks every other app besides the ones on a whitelist, by just telling your system to either close it the second it's open, or minimize it (you can choose) for a specific amount of time. However, this program isn't available on Linux, only on Windows and MacOS.

Comment: There are probably already applications that do this, search for productivity and focus apps.

Comment: Yea, I am inspired by one of them, but I kinda want to make it myself, its not gonna be as good, but its good code practice and I can make it more specific for my situation.

Comment: if you nspired by some program then you could show link to this program. And add it in question, not in comments, so more people will see it.

Comment: in `Tkinter` you may try to display window with option `fullscreen` and `topmost` and it will hide other elements and keep window always on top of other windows. But I'm not sure if it can stop key shortcuts to minimize window or open main menu

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on adding the inspiration source to the problem, just edited it. I'll check out the tkinter suggestion, however I am looking for something that would let me interact with the whole OS by using python.

Comment: Maybe something with the OS module is possible?